# How to map data into cards react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple shop in react.js.
My next step would be mapping the products which I store in data.js file into separate cards and then a product list. I am using external libraries for Card.

This is data.js (example):

```
 export const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "example title",
      content: "example content",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/example.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "example title",
      content: "example content",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/example.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "example title",
      content: "example content",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/example.jpg"
    },
    ]
```

That would be a component rendering a single product card:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import { data } from '../../../data'


const Product = () => (


  <Col xs={12} md={6} lg={4} key={data.id}>
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Card.Header></Card.Header>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={data.image} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{data.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
          {data.content}
        </Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
        <Button>Add to favs</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  </Col>
)

export default Product;
```

and finally, the component rendring many products:

```
import React from 'react';

import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import {data} from '../../../data'

import Product  from '../Product/Product';

import styles from './Shop.module.scss';

const Shop = () => {

  return (
   
      <div className='row-wrapper'>
        <Row>
           {data.map(product => (
            <Product key={product.id} {...product} />
          ))}  
        </Row>
      </div>
    ) 
  
};

export default Shop;
```

This does not work, I receive errors in the console. What am I missing?

edit: the error I get:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

stacktrace:

> Blockquote
> Check your code at Product.js:13.
> in Product (at Shop.js:17)
> in div (created by Row)
> in Row (at Shop.js:15)
> in div (at Shop.js:14)
> in Shop (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Route (at Header.js:24)
> in Switch (at Header.js:22)
> in div (at Header.js:13)
> in Header (at MainLayout.js:15)
> in div (at MainLayout.js:13)
> in MainLayout (at App.js:12)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at App.js:11)
> in App (at src/index.js:6)

Comment: Destructure `id`, `title`, `content`, and `image` from the passed props (`{...product}`) in `Product` and render directly, i.e. it'll be just `title`, not `data.title`.

Comment: the error says: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: try removing `import { data } from '../../../data'` from Product component. plus what @DrewReese said.

Comment: Which import or component is undefined? Where is the error pointing to? What line of code? Can you include the stacktrace in your question?

Comment: @Shweta patel still the same, unfortunately

Comment: @Drew Reese sure, doing it now

Comment: this error shows 65 times

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using? I don't think the `Card` component is a compound component.

Comment: @Drew Reese yes, I thinkthat is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the product details from the shop component to the Product Component through the props, the following code should works:

Product Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';


const Product = ({product}) => (


  <Col xs={12} md={6} lg={4} key={product.id}>
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Card.Header></Card.Header>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={product.image} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{product.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
          {product.content}
        </Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
        <Button>Add to favs</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  </Col>
)

export default Product;
```

Shop Component

```
import React from 'react';

import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import {data} from '../../../data'

import Product  from '../Product/Product';

import styles from './Shop.module.scss';

const Shop = () => {

  return (
   
      <div className='row-wrapper'>
        <Row>
           {data.map(product => (
            <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
          ))}  
        </Row>
      </div>
    ) 
  
};

export default Shop;
```